# Azure Bicep BP165 Error - A resource's computed scope must match that of the Bicep file for it to be deployable

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'm trying to use bicep to deploy an apim backend resource into an existing apim instance. This is the relevant section of my apim mdoule:

```
resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-08-01' existing = {
  name: apimName
  scope: resourceGroup(apimRG)
}

var funcAppName = 'func-nurseryfees-${env}-001'
resource backend 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends@2022-04-01-preview' = {
  name: 'backend_${funcAppName}'
  parent: apim
  properties: {
    description: 'backend for ${funcAppName}'
    url: 'https://func-nurseryfees-${env}-001.azurewebsites.net/api'
    protocol: 'http'
    credentials: {
      header: {
        'x-functions-key': [
          '{{func-nurseryfees-dev-001-key}}'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, vscode gives the following error:

> A resource's computed scope must match that of the Bicep file for it
> to be deployable. This resource's scope is computed from the "scope"
> property value assigned to ancestor resource "apim". You must use
> modules to deploy resources to a different scope.bicep(BCP165)

The bicep module works ok if I remove the section for the backend resource.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: what is the scope of the module at deployment time ? also could you please paste the full module + how you invoke it  please ?

Comment: There's no scope defined: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2021-08-01/service?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: The scope is set on the parent resource - the apim service

Comment: would you be avble to share both main and module please ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I think I've fixed the problem! The bicep was being run from a multi-stage devops yaml template. The previous stage deployed a func app to an rg. The apim stage tried to run the bicep above using 'az deployment group create' but passing the name of the rg of the fun app. I've now changed the yaml of the apim stage to pass the name of the apim rg. I've also removed the scope prop from the apim resource of the apim bicep. That seems to have fixed it but I don't understand why the 1st approach didn't work - I'd have expected the scope prop to win over the scope set by the az command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of the problem was the 'az deployment group create' command that was used to execute the bicep was passing the name of the wrong resource group.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing the issue and you're passing the correct Resource Group from a main.bicep file deploying to a subscription then remove the scope property entirely:

```
resource APIM 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-03-01-preview' existing = {
  name: APIManagementName
}
```